# Clipboard.GetText() always empty

Tags: c#

`Clipboard.GetText()` always empty, I want to copy the text in my clipboard inside my app

```
var str = Clipboard.GetText();
```

but it's always empty! why is that? where it has data.

Comment: On which operating system do you test? As per MSDN documentation, getting an empty string might be an expected behaviour: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kz40084e(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Add this code statement before: `Clipboard.SetText("Bugs Bunny");`  Is `str` still empty?